# Display image in system configuration?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, adminhtml, configuration

> I want to display a image for radio button value in system
>   configuration.

As well i want to show that selected image in my front-end.

Help me to do this.

Thanks

Comment: First I guess this is a custom config value, could you please show us the code that you have to start with. Secondly where do you want to show this in the front end?

Answer (score 2):

To add a input type file you have to add below code in system.xml file of your specific module. paste the below code in `<fields>` section.

```
<file translate="label comment">
    <label>File</label>
    <frontend_type>file</frontend_type>
    <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_file</backend_model>
    <upload_dir>var/uploads</upload_dir>
    <sort_order>70</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</file>
```

To get this Image Name on front side

```
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName');
```

**sectionName, groupName and fieldName** are present in etc/system.xml file of your module.